# Trouble finding a sequence formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence goes:

1,$\frac{2}{3}$,$\frac{7}{9}$,$\frac{20}{27}$,$\frac{61}{81}$

I tried using the common difference method of analysis and found the second row follows the rule: multiply by $\frac{-1}{3}$, Third row onwards seems to follow the rule: multiply by $\frac{1}{3}$. I did find the formula:

$x(n)=x(n-1)+ (\frac{-1}{3})^{n}$

$x(0)=1$

I can't figure out how to make this into a formula that doesn't depend on previous values.

1,$\frac{2}{3}$,$\frac{7}{9}$,$\frac{20}{27}$,$\frac{61}{81}$

\ /\ /\ /  \ /

$\frac{-1}{3}$$\frac{1}{9}$$\frac{-1}{27}$$\frac{1}{81}$

\ / \ /  \ /

$\frac{4}{9}$ $\frac{4}{27}$ $\frac{4}{81}$

\ / \ /

$\frac{-8}{27}$ $\frac{-8}{81}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You correctly noticed that the difference between terms is given by $\left(-\frac13\right)^i$.
So to get the $n^{th}$ term you need to add this expression from $1$ to $n$ (add potentially add a constant to get the first term correct).

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left(-\frac13\right)^i$$

This is a GP so the sum becomes:

$$\frac{-\frac13\left(1-\left(-\frac13\right)^n\right)}{1-\left(-\frac13\right)}$$

$$=\frac{-1+\left(-\frac13\right)^n}{4}$$

Subbing in $n=1$ gives a value of $-\frac13$ so we need to add the constant $1$ to the expression to get the desired starting term. Hence the formula is:

$$\frac{3+\left(-\frac13\right)^n}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write $a_0=b_0=1$ and $a_{n+1}=3\cdot a_n-\frac{1+(-1)^{n+1}}{2},$ $b_{n+1}=3\cdot b_n$ to finally write you sequence as $c_n=\frac{a_n}{b_n}.$ Note that $b_n=3^n$ and that you can note $c_{n+1}=c_n-\frac{1+(-1)^{n+1}}{2\cdot 3^n}.$